# How do the Scouts, MP's and Garrison personnel survive landing at high speed after killing a titan?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In Attack on Titan we see alot of titan kills, But how do the people survive/ land after doing this?

[image]

What was even going to do if he actually killed the colossal titan? He would slam into its nape at high speed (I don't know how fast the ODM is) he doesn't look like he was trying to brace or anything. And again with Mikasa:[image] as I said before I don't know how fast is the ODM but when Eren and Mikasa have that epice scene of them getting to the boulder using ODM gear. the building in the background was going away at a very fast rate so, point is that its fast, very fast. so how would someone land safely under these speeds?

Comment: Regarding the speed: [How fast is the 3D Maneuver Gear (3DMG)?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/22091/how-fast-is-the-3d-maneuver-gear-3dmg?rq=1)

Comment: so the top speed is 55 mph??? I really don't think this is the top speed of the ODM gear. But even at this speed landing would be an issue.

Comment: I believe Worldbuilding SE has a similar/related question:  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/127303/can-we-build-a-3d-maneuver-gear-from-attack-on-titan

Comment: You seem to disagree with the estimated top speed. If you think you can provide a better estimate, by all means do so. People can ask and answer their own questions. Also, they are not slamming against the titan to kill them, they are only slicing its nape. Landing on them is only optional and would likely get them killed. Landing on other surfaces require slowing down so I assume they would do this since IIRC, the ODM gear has a control for speeding/slowing down.

Comment: But im bad at math ... welp google gonna come in handy